# Recovering $X,Y,Z$ from $x,y,z$ in CIE color model.

Tags: linear-algebra

The background of where I'm getting this from is less important, [but you can read it if you like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_xyY#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space).

The question is, given three variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, all ranging from $0$ to $1$, we can construct a *normalized* transform:
$$x =\frac{X}{X + Y + Z} \\
y = \frac{Y}{X + Y + Z}\\
z =\frac{Z}{X + Y + Z} = 1 - x - y$$

They state the extra relation:
$$z = (1 - x - y)$$

I'm not sure how they arrive at it; but it may be useful or important in answering my question:

> Given only "little" $x$, $y$, $z$, is it possible to recover "big" $X$, $Y$, $Z$?

## Similar solution

They do give a way to recover $X$ and $Z$ if you already know $Y$:
$$X = \frac{Y}y \times x\\
Z = \frac{Y}y \times (1-x-y)$$

I'm not certain how they managed to arrive at those solutions, [and neither was Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+A+%2F+%28A%2BB%2BC%29%2C+y+%3D+B+%2F+%28A%2BB%2BC%29%2C+z+%3D+C+%2F+%28A%2BB%2BC%29%2C+solve++C). But, again, maybe its helpful to answering my question.

## The question

> Is it possible, knowing the above transform, and that $XYZ$ ranges between $0$ and $1$, to recover $XYZ$ from $xyz$?

Comment: Note that $$x + y + z = \frac{X}{X+Y+Z} + \frac{Y}{X+Y+Z} + \frac{Z}{X+Y+Z} = \frac{X+Y+Z}{X+Y+Z} = 1,$$ from which the identity $$z = 1-x-y$$ immediately follows.

Comment: The answer is NO. This is because the map $(X,Y,Z) \mapsto (x,y,z)$ is not one to one. Under the map, both $(X,Y,Z) = (1,1,1)$ and $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ get mapped to same $(x,y,z) = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$.

Comment: And yes, sorry for not taking the time to learn the markdown syntax for formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the solution is not unique: the system is underdetermined because of the relationship between $x, y, z$ (their sum is always 1).  So in fact we only have two equations in three unknowns, whose solution can be given by $$Y = \frac{y}{x} X, \quad Z = \frac{z}{x} X.$$  Under the constraint that $0 \le X, Y, Z \le 1$, it follows that we can choose any $X$ such that $0 < X \le \min \{ x/y, x/z \}$.  If $x = 0$, then choose a different permutation of the variables--at least one is guaranteed to be nonzero, again since $x+y+z = 1$.